# Is there a way, if so which, to color certain areas in C ++ (Console) in the background, if you know what I mean?

Tags: c++, console

So I want to write a console application, and for that I want to color certain areas in the background, so something like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Imkxx.png)

Just that you know what i want to do, not exactly this, but i want paint the background.

(My English is not very good)

Comment: Unfortunately, questions seeking tools/libraries are off-topic here, so this'll likely be closed. That being said, I'd advise you to look into [ncurses](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/). If you have specific questions about getting programs using it working, feel free to come back and ask!

Comment: In your image, the console is achieving the color by using "block" characters.  The console is switched to a foreground color (red), then the blocks are drawn.  There are no special tricks.  You will need to find out if your console supports colored text, and how to set the text color.  Otherwise, use a GUI or windowing system.